# Insert a row at certain points in a datatable?

Tags: asp.net

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name   Hours
Mark   10
Mark   15
Mark   10
Mark   13
Albert 11
Albert 12
Max    10
Max    13
```

This data resides in a datatable, which is the datasource for my gridview.  I would like to, if possible, iterate through the datatable and insert a row when the Name field changes.  Like this:

```
Name   Hours
Mark   10
Mark   15
Mark   10
Mark   13

Albert 11
Albert 12

Max    10
Max    13
```

Is it possible to use a foreach loop to iterate through this datatable and upon the name changing, insert a row at that point?  Or, is there another method to get the desired result?

Thanks for any pointers!

EDIT:  My code, so far:

```
        var counter = 0;
        var holdName = "";
        // looping through datatable dt.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
           //compare name from dt to hold name
           //if different
           //  insert blank row
           //  change hold name to new name
           //continue looping 
        }
        gridview1.Datasource = dt;
        gridview1.DataBind();
```

The problem, though is that setting the hold name within the loop is proving tricky.  It's like it needs to be set 'ouside' the loop, first, and then checked within the loop.  The problem is, how do I know what the name is without getting the first record in the datatable?  Perhaps, that is my answer?  Get the first record, put the name in the hold name variable, then start the foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, `foreach` loops certainly will provide a viable solution.

Comment: The insertion order should never matter, use an order by clause instead. Edit - wait are you talking about some kind of UI element or the DB table? It's very unclear what you mean.

Comment: I agree with asawyer, you do not need to iterate through the database and insert at a specific point. Insert a new row in the database table and then use SQL to properly retrieve the data in a certain order (ORDER BY clause) or filtered list of data (WHERE clause). Do not try to have your UI be SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Sorry if I am being obtuse.  The data is not in a database table.  It is in a DataTable.  The data is already in the preferred order, I just want to insert blank rows when I put it in my gridview.

Comment: Also, to whoever downgraded my question, I'd appreciate it if you could point out what I could do to make this a better question.  Thanks!

Comment: @JavaRox - How about insert a new row and then have the grid view sorted by whatever rules you want after the insertion?

Comment: Oh, you want to have a blank row in between your groupings of rows in the GridView display? Why exactly, what is the use case here?

Comment: @Karl, Correct.  Just something to breakup the gridview display so that when the name changes, there will be a blank row before the next section of names/hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will get better results if you use the ASP.NET ListView control and use data groupings, like this:

[Using ASP.NET 3.5's ListView and DataPager Controls: Grouping By a Data Field](https://web.archive.org/web/20210301194237/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091708-1.aspx)

It is a slightly dated article, but I think it will get you to where you want to go.

Comment: Thanks,Karl!  I'll check that link out real quick.  I appreciate it!

Comment: That ListView looks like it may be the ticket that I'm looking for.  With the inherent ability for grouping, it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for!  Thanks, Karl!

Answer (score 1):

As Brad M already stated, a `foreach` loop will work. You just need to store the name in a variable and check if the name of the current row is the same as the name in the last row (or you could check if the name in the current row is the same as the name in the next row. But this could lead to a OutOfBoundsException).

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do now.  My foreach loop uses a variable to hold the name and when it gets the next record, if the name is different from my 'hold' name, I want to insert a blank row, and make the 'hold' name whatever the new name is.

Comment: @JavaRox: You can try `Rows.InsertAt(DataRow, index)`and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, waka, for your help.  I decided to go with Karl's answer, just because it looks like the ListView may be better suited for what I'm trying to do than using a GridView.  I appreciate your help!